# Finiteness of a homomorphism between polynomial rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Let $A=k[X,Y]/(XY)$ and the homomorphism $k[T]\rightarrow A$ given by $T\to X+Y$. Show that this homomorphism is injective and finite.

For the injectivity, I can see that it works because the kernel of the homomorphism is given by $k[T]\cap (XY)=0$.

For the finiteness, I need to prove that $k[X,Y]/(XY)$ is a $k[T]$-module finitely generated. I don't know how to do this, any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Actually the kernel is $\{f\in K[T]:f(X+Y)\in(XY)\}$, and it is some work to do in order to show that this is $(0)$.

Comment: Isn't it $0$ because there is no $f\neq 0$ such that $f(X+Y)$ can be expressed only on powers of $XY$? there will always survive powers of $X$ and $Y$ isolated.

Comment: In fact, from $f(X+Y)=XYg(X,Y)$ we get $f(X)=0$ by sending $Y$ to $0$, and we are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can prove that $K[X,Y]/(XY)$ is a finitely generated $K[x+y]$-module, where $x,y$ are the residue classes of $X,Y$ modulo the ideal $(XY)$. You know that $xy=0$. Then $x,y$ are the roots of the polynomial $(Z-x)(Z-y)=Z^2-(x+y)Z\in K[x+y][Z]$, so $K[x+y]\subset K[x,y]$ is an integral ring extension, and it is finitely generated for $K[x+y][x,y]=K[x,y]$, so $K[x,y]$ is a finitely generated $K[x+y]$-module.